# How to save the Canvas in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to implement small online drawing and image tools. For this reason I liked to use fabric. In my program I would like to send the canvas to PHP. Or else I want to save the canvas as jpeg image in the web directory.

How can you save or export the result of a canvas as an image.

Comment: Why did you close this question? this is absolutely a valid question for a newbie to HTML5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032214/recreate-fabric-js-canvas-and-export-as-an-image