# Recreate Fabric.js canvas and export as an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas where the user can create a design using images in another `div` that they click, sending it to the Fabric.js canvas where it gets moved around and so on. Since the canvas's size is `width="270"`and `height="519"`, smaller than what the finished product is, I need to recreate it with a canvas that has the size `width="1001"`and `height="1920"` and then screenshot it so that I get it all in 1 single image. How do I do this?

This is what my code looks like so far:

***HTML***

```
<div id="CanvasContainer">
    <canvas id="Canvas" width="270" height="519"></canvas>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#CanvasContainer {
    width: 270px;
    height: 519px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#Canvas {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
//Defining Canvas and object array
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('Canvas');

//When clicked
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Backgrounds img").click(function () {
        var getId = $(this).attr("id");

        //adding all clicked images
        var imgElement = document.getElementById(getId);
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
            left: 135,
            top: 259,
            width: 270,
            height: 519
        });
        //Corner color for clicked images
        imgInstance.set({
            borderColor: 'white',
            cornerColor: 'black',
            transparentCorners: false,
            cornerSize: 12
        });
        canvas.add(imgInstance);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Fabric has a built in function to convert to data urls. You can use the download property of a link to make the link a download link. Finally you can use the DOM `click()` function to emulate clicking the download link. The end result is:

```
function download(url,name){
// make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({href:url,download:name})[0].click();
}
function downloadFabric(canvas,name){
//  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  download(canvas.toDataURL(),name+'.png');
}
```

now when you want to download the canvas call

```
downloadFabric(canvas,'<file name>');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having some troubles getting this to work in Firefox and Safari. It works well in Chrome. In Safari this code opens a new tab. In Firefox it does nothing

Comment: @kyledavide I know it's been a while but do you know if anything like this exists for SVG and not PNG?

Comment: @code4ever there is a method toSvg() to get a svg string of the canvas, but from there you would need to build the data URL manually. I'm away from my computer right now, but I'll make a snippet when I get back.

Comment: @kyledavide I look forward to seeing that!

Comment: If you'd like, too, I can create a new question

Comment: @code4ever It  would be something along the lines of: https://gist.github.com/KyleDavidE/a1980e82d149e899728250557234ebd9